# right shift operator on hexadecimal in turbo c++

Tags: c, hex, shift, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int x=0x01c0ffee;
int y=x>>15+1&0xff;
clrscr();
printf("%x  ",y);
getch();
}
```

the following code prints ff in turbo c++ and instead of
15+1
if we use
7+1
returns the same answer ff.
so, does turbo c++ considers x>> 8 and x>>16 same on hexa,something like that?

Comment: And the left-shift operator is... where ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Poster probably meant *right* shift.

Comment: If this is turbo C, then `int` is 16-bits, meaning your `x` is `ffee`, and thus shifting it 16 bits (15 + 1) will give you a result of 0xff, whatever number of right shifts you make (8 or more).

Comment: Why anyone uses a compiler that is old enough to get a driving license in most countries is beyond me. But hey, who am I to judge that, I did use it in 1992 or so.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I was under the impression that shifting a 16-bit type 16 places results in UB.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Many engineering colleges in India use Turbo C++. Weird and sad but true.

Comment: Technically it is. Since the hardware Turbo C++ runs on is x86, and it PROBABLY doesn't do something more complicated than a SAR ("Shift Arithmetic Right"), the result would be 0xff - of course, it's valid to build a compiler that gives another result - for example using `SHR` which would give the result 0. But for most purpose using `SAR` makes more sense, so that's what I expect the compiler to do. The main point is that the OP expects a 32-bit integer, which is probably not the case.

Comment: @WhozCraig  It's shifting to the left if you are standing behind the code.

Comment: @Kunal: Yes, sadly, that is true. I don't quite understand why.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have changed the title of the question...

Answer (score 1):

To debug your code, I would suggest breaking down the output into the individual operations, but also check that you have enough room in your variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 0x01c0ffee;
    int y = x >> 15 + 1 & 0xff;

    printf("Size: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("1.) %x\n", x);
    printf("2.) %x\n", x >> 15);
    printf("3.) %x\n", x >> 15 + 1);
    printf("4.) %x\n", x >> 15 + 1 & 0xFF);

    printf("Final: %x\n",y);
}
```

The output of `Size:` will show you how many bytes you have for `int`. You need one byte for every two hexademical digit.

Here is the output on my 32-bit machine:

```
Size: 4
1.) 1c0ffee
2.) 381
3.) 1c0
4.) c0
Final: c0
```

If you see `Size: 2`, then there's your problem. Try using `long int`.
Also, I would recommend using `unsigned` if you're performing shift operations since the behavior of right-shift on `signed` variables is implementation-specific (which means Turbo C could act different from gcc)